# Java: Mapping array elements to a set of properties

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I have multidimensional `double[][]` arrays of which each element has a set of properties.

I designed these properties as a Class:

```
public class ElemProperties 
{
    public double prop1;

    ...     
}
```

Linking them with the elements of the array using a HashMap:

```
HashMap<double[][], ElemProperties> elemProperties;
```

using it like e.g:

```
elemProperties.get(exampleArray).getProp1();
```

However, this only serves as a mapping between the whole array and properties. What I'm trying to do is to actually map the *elements*. Since Java doesn't have pointers, I'm kind of stuck at this position. This design seems very convoluted is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html  java.util.Properties?

Comment: It is very convoluted indeed. I would start thinking about objects rather than arrays and maps. Unfortunately I can't really make out the structure you want to achieve from the question.

Comment: @biziclop I tried to rephrase the question. I think you're right, I was just trying to avoid a major refactoring, trying to link the existing data structures.

Comment: I don't quite get your concept. Why do both the key and the value represent the properties?

Comment: @runDOSrun Okay, it's getting clearer now. What I would start with is to wrap the `double` value and all the other properties into a single object. Then you can have a two-dimensional array of that object instead of `double[][]`. This would be a better representation conceptually but still isn't very efficient.

Comment: @Bubletan The key represents the object of the array that the set of properties (value) belongs to.

Comment: You shouldn't use an array as the key to your Map, think about what would happen if the array changed. If the ElemProperties are properties for a specific value in your multidimensional array use Map<Double, ElemProperties>

Comment: @biziclop Tanks, I think that sounds very reasonable from a conceptual POV.

Comment: @JimW The difficulty is that they are properties for specific *fields* and not *values* in the array, i.e. the doubles are subject to change and can't be used as keys either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First attempt would be:

```
public class Elem {
    private double value;
    private double additionalProperty1;
    private double additionalProperty2;
    ...
}
```

And create an `Elem[][]` instead of a `double[][]`.

This at least works but multi-dimensional arrays aren't too efficient and aren't too expressive either, so the next question is whether you could group them using a different structure.

If the additional properties are optional or could be shared between multiple elements, you would need to write objects for them too, but the starting point is the same.

---

It is of course possible that you genuinely need a `Map` to link values to additional properties "because of reasons". In that case you can do something like this:

```
public class Container {
   private double[][] values;
   private Map<Double,AdditionalProperties> properties;

   public double getValue(int x, int y) {
     return values[x][y];
   }

   public AdditionalProperties getProperties(int x, int y) {
     return properties.get( getValue(x, y ) );
   }
 }
```

This way you can hide the fact that you use two separate data structures to store the data, and maintain data integrity between them.

Note though that this is semantically very different from the first solution. In particular, positions containing the same value will share their `AdditionalProperties`.

(There are also practical problems with this implementation, @dasblinkenlight already pointed out why using `double`s as keys to a map is an issue, the other is that an autoboxing conversion happens and that can add some memory and run time overhead. All these problems can be overcome with careful coding, but I'm only demonstrating the basic concept here.)

Comment: That's it, thanks! I feel silly for not having thought of this. It solves the problems that come from using primitives as elements when in fact I needed Objects to properly reference them.

Answer (score 2):

> since the `HashMap` compares for references this works.

Comparing for references also happens to be the biggest problem with this approach: the fact that the object is a 2d array of `double` does not matter - one could simply replace your map with

```
HashMap<Object,ElemProperties> elemProperties;
```

without losing any functionality.

A better approach would be making a class that represents 2D keys based on arrays of `double`:

```
class KeyDouble2D {
    private final double[][] key;
    public KeyDouble2D(double[][] key) {
        // Make a copy of key into this.key
    }
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // Ensure that other is KeyDouble2D, then compare key
        // sizes, and finally compare arrays element-by-element.
        // Make sure to use `Double.equals` method to avoid NaN != NaN problem.
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        // Compute hash code as a sum of hash codes in 2D array
    }
}
```

You can use this class for keys of your hash map:

```
HashMap<KeyDouble2D,ElemProperties> elemProperties = ...;
...
ElemProperties prop = elemProperties.get(new KeyDouble2D(exampleArray)).getProp1();
```

Note that one needs to be very careful when using arrays of `double` for hash keys, for the same reason why one needs to be careful when comparing `double`s for equality.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a class `DoubleWithProperties`, and manipulate an array of this class, instead of using a hashmap?

```
class DoubleWithProperties {
   double value;
   ElemProperties props;
   public DoubleWithProperties(double value, ElemProperties props){
   ...
   }
}
DoubleWithProperties[][] array = new DoubleWithProperties[5][5];
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the simplest approach.